# ngrx: check is store already have the same object before dispatch action

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have action, which add new object to a store:

```
let warning = {message: 'some text', status: 'suspended'} 
this.store.dispatch(new WarningActions.AddWarning(warning))
```

but if I already have the same warning, I don't want to add it again, so I tried to check store before dispatch it:

```
this.store.select('warning').subscribe(warnings => {
   console.log(warnings) // [{message: 'some text', status: 'suspended'}]
   if (warnings.indexOf(warning) === -1) {
     this.store.dispatch(new WarningActions.AddWarning(warning))
   }
})
```

But this is does not work, because `warnings.indexOf(warning) === -1` always yields true, even if I already have exactly the same object. What I did wrong and how I can solve this?

Comment: what if you do the same on reducer? and if it's exists don't update store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`indexOf()` will always return `-1` because they are two distinct objects and cannot equal even if they look the same (i.e. have the same properties and values).

you may use the `some` method to find if the properties are same.

Comment: if(warnings.some(warn => warn.message ===warning.message && warn.status === warning.status)){}

Comment: You could include the code sample in the answer (instead of giving it as a comment).

Answer (score 1):

You can not deeply compare objects in Javascript this way. `{} === {}` is `false` no matter what you do. You need to compare the properties manually. If you want deep comparison in JS have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript).